# Multibitrate streaming in ipad using flowplayer

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, rtmp, flowplayer

Using flowplayer (flash version) I'm able to load multibitrate video files via smil file using rtmp protocol.

The respective script follows

```
<script>
flowplayer("bplayer", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", {
    clip: {
        url: "bitrates3.smil.xml",
        autoPlay: true,
        provider: 'rtmp',
        urlResolvers: [ 'smil', 'bwcheck' ]
    },
    plugins: {

         smil: {
            url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.smil-3.2.8.swf"
        },
bwcheck: {
    url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.bwcheck-3.2.11.swf",
    serverType: 'wowza',
    dynamic: true,
    netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://video.abc.com/cdn',
   },
rtmp: {
    url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.11.swf",
    netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://video.abc.com/cdn'
},
}
}).ipad();
</script>
```

This is the smil file - bitrates3.smil.xml (video paths are dummy)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smil>
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://itl.bc-s.cdn.bitgravity.com/cdn" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="mp4:/abc/secure/A-081207-L.mp4" system-bitrate="800" width="480" />
      <video src="mp4:/abc/secure/A-081207-M.mp4?" system-bitrate="1200" width="720" />
      <video src="mp4:/abc/secure/A-081207-S.mp4?" system-bitrate="1600" width="1080" />
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

I can also independently play video on iPad using the ipad plugin associated with flowplayer.

The respective code follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    head.js(
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js",
        "http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js",
        "http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.11.min.js", function(){

head.js("http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer.ipad-3.2.12.min.js");

    });
  $f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf").ipad();

 </script>
<!-- player container-->
<a href="http://video.abc.com/secure/A-20110128-L.mp4?e=0"    class="player"     style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;margin:10px auto" id="player"> <img src="dummy-image.jpg" alt="Search engine friendly content" /> </a>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I combine these codes so that the multibitrate switching must work for all browsers and devices? I've the necessary formats of video files for supporting different devices/browsers.

I tried to add the http video link in the clip's ipadURL property and invoked the ipad() function but then i just got a blank black screen and nothing worked (not even on the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTMP will not work on Ipad. RTMP is a flash streaming protocol. For IOS, HTTP-live-streaming is protocol to use for streaming.

Comment: OK, I understand.. But in the demo shown here http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/audio-live.html we can set an ipad url in the clip. We've tried the http version of our video file as ipadUrl.

Comment: Ok,Now I see that you have a http url for Ipad

Comment: HTML5 with fallback to flash is the way to go to support Video streaming on all browsers. Something like this: http://blog.ianbeyer.com/tag/html5/